# SpecFlow features are not recognized in test explorer

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, nunit, specflow

I added NUnit, NUnit Test Adapter, SpecFlow and my test are not recognized in test explorer. If I run the test from the feature file, with right click, it says that the build was succesful, but nothing happens and it's terminated in 0,001 sec. I check the default processor architecture too, but its ok. How can I solve it any ideas?

**Login.feature**

```
Feature: Login
    Test the login functionality of application
    Will verify if the username and password combinations are working as expected

@Regressiontest
@Browser:Chrome
Scenario Outline: Verify if the login functionality is working (+ve case)
    Given I have navigated to my application
    And I typed the <username> and <password>
    When I click login button
    Then I should see the EA page

Examples:
 | username | password |
 | admin    | admin    |
 | karthik  | karthik  |
```

Comment: What is displayed in the `Output` window where `Show output from` is set to `Tests`?

Comment: yes, it is but it's empty [https://prnt.sc/ltqfuj] - [http://prntscr.com/ltqh29]

Comment: Are there any errors in the Build Output? Is there valid code in `Login.feature.cs`?

Comment: NUnit and NUnit3 Test Adapter versions weren't the same, so that's why the tests weren't recognized in test explorer. Now I can run them but I got an other error [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734102/exception-while-invoking-the-constructor-autofac-dependency-error]

Answer (score 0):

NUnit and NUnit3 Test Adapter versions weren't the same, so that's why the tests weren't recognized in test explorer.