# exception while invoking the constructor autofac dependency error

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, autofac, blink

**Message**`: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'ChromeDriver'. ---> unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: 2ac50e7249fbd55e6f517a28131605c9fb9fe897
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (See inner exception for details.)
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision: 2ac50e7249fbd55e6f517a28131605c9fb9fe897
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267521,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**Standard Output**:`warning: The previous ScenarioContext was already disposed.`

I can't find out where is the problem and I didn't get any solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Chrome do you have installed?

Chrome driver v2.10 is rather old.

Have you tried using the latest version?

For example, http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/